# how to remove forward slash from specific url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccessfile

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And I have the following url:

```
http://localhost/mysite/loginPage/
```

I want to ensure that this url will never ends with forward slash (loginPage/).

I tried to use the following lines:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[^/]+)/.+$ - [L,R=404]
```

But I get error message in all cases that page is not redirecting properly. Please have in mind that I want this just for the specific URL above, i don't care for the rest of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want this just for the specific URL above

In that case, your rule should just match specifically this URI rather than `.*/.*` etc.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/mysite/loginPage)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

You don't really need `QSA` flag in last rule also.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you put the rule for your rewrite. The examples you provided do work. But you have to put them before your last htaccess line.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will create the proper output, and can be tested through something like a [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

If you want it specifically for just that url you could resort to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mysite/loginPage/$ mysite/loginPage? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You could also specify an absolute redirect with

```
RewriteRule ^mysite/loginPage/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/mysite/loginPage? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't know what is the issue but nothing works. I get either 404 error messages either strange errors like that yoursite/c:\www\root\yoursite cant be found....

Comment: Should I have the RewriteEngine on on the top of the .htaccess or not?

Comment: Yes, that should always be on top of any RewriteCond or RewriteRule. Is there anything else inside the htaccess that could interfere? you could also try an absolute redirect. Change the mysite/loginPage to http://%{HTTP_HOST}%mysite/loginPage

Comment: After I include it I get now You don't have permission to access /C:/prj/www/nbo/backEnd on this server . This is happening if I use the first solution.